# import pandas returning 'no module named pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, modulenotfounderror

I cannot use pandas in my script. It's my first time using a package, and it doesn't work. When I use pip install pandas the cmd prompt returns:

```html
PS C:\Users\young> pip install pandas
3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\young\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)       
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\users\young\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pandas) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\users\young\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pandas) (1.21.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\young\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.1PS C:\Users\young> pip3.9 install wheel
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\young\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (0.36.2)
```

included in the snippet is pip install wheel, so I have that covered.

Comment: Check if you have made an typo? While importting?

Comment: I didnt make any typos

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This shows that pandas was already installed. Try to import and use.

Comment: When I write 'import pandas' in VS Code it gives me an error, that's the problem. The code is literally just the line import pandas.

Comment: try to install pandas through the IDE interpreter

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical issue with multi installation of python. Please check if you have more than one installation of Python.
if yes than ........

You can  check where your installed packages should be saved with the following

import os
os.path
and then install using the following terminal instruction

pip3 install pandas -t /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet shows that pandas module was already installed on your device. Now, simply type

```
`import pandas`
```

and start writing the coding. It should not give you any errors.

If you are using an ios device then `pip3 install _pakage name_` or you can use `Sudo` also as `pip` does not work for me.

Comment: When I write 'import pandas' in VS Code it gives me an error, that's the problem. The code is literally just the line import pandas. –

I have the same problem with importing 'keyboard'

I suggest you try to delete and reinstall pandas, if it still does not work, then use another command.

Answer (score 0):

See if a folder named pandas is already there (where it says it is or where your editor/python keeps the packages), If so, delete that and try again.  Try restarting your editor (sometimes that works with pycharm if it's being laggy, for me at least).

Also, that is not what returns when I try to install pandas.
Make sure your command is `pip install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any file/folder named `pandas` in the working directory of your python file. If yes, then rename it. Otherwise Python would import that file instead of the pandas module.